# Firestore pagination with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Using bootstrap-vue pagination component:

```
<b-pagination
  v-model="currentPage"
  :total-rows="rows"
  :per-page="perPage"
></b-pagination>
```

Component.vue:

```
export default class Links extends Vue {
  public currentPage: number = 1
  public perPage: number = 20
  public rows: number = 1

  @Watch('currentPage')
  onCurrentPageChange(page: number) {
    const startAt = page * this.perPage - this.perPage
    db.collection('links')
      .orderBy('created', 'desc')
      .startAt(startAt)
      .limit(this.perPage)
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        console.log(snap.docs)
      })
  }
}
```

When `currentPage` value changes, i fetch new DB values with `startAt` but it returns nothing. My firestore has the following documents with the fields:

- created (date)
- title (string)
- url (string)

How can i make a normal pagination with offsets / limits?

Answer (score 2):

I have also had similar problem with pagination. The documentation seems to be insufficient i.e they show you how to go to next page but not how to move back to the previous page. Its just frustrating really.

Below is how i implemented a simple pagination. I have already configured `VueFire` , `Firebase` and `BootstrapVue`  i'll head straight to the code.

**What to do different that no one shows you.**

- Use `VueFire` programmatic binding instead of declarative binding [see here](https://v2.vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#programmatic-binding)
- To get `firstVisible` item in `firebase` run `documentSnapshots.docs[0]`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>{{countries}}</p>
         <b-button-group size="lg" class="mx-2">
      <b-button :disabled="prev_btn" @click="previous" >&laquo;</b-button>
      <b-button :disabled="next_btn" @click="next">&raquo;</b-button>
    </b-button-group>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
 import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import { db } from '../main'

export default {
 name: 'Countries',
 data () {
  return {
   countries: [],
   limit: 2,
   lastVisible: '',
   firstVisible: '',
   next_btn: false,
   prev_btn: true
  }
 },
 methods: {
  next () {
   if (!this.next_btn) {
   // bind data with countries
    this.$bind('countries', db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(this.lastVisible).limit(this.limit))
    // set last and first visible items
    db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(this.lastVisible).limit(this.limit).get().then(documentSnapshots => {
     this.lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1]
     this.firstVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[0]
    }).then(() => {
     // Peep  on the next  next query to see if it gives zero
     db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(this.lastVisible).limit(this.limit).get()
      .then(snap => {
       if (snap.size === 0) {
        //disable button if the next peeped result gets zero
        this.next_btn = true
        // enable previous button
        this.prev_btn = false
       } else {
        // enable next button if peeped result is not zero
        this.next_btn = false
        // enable previous button
        this.prev_btn = false
       }
      })
    })
   }
  },
  previous () {
   // Ensure previous is not zero
   db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').endBefore(this.firstVisible).limitToLast(this.limit).get().then(snap => { return snap.size })
   .then(size => {
    //confirm is not zero here
    if (size !== 0) {
     //bind the previous to countries
     this.$bind('countries', db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').endBefore(this.firstVisible).limitToLast(this.limit))
     // Set last and first visible
     db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').endBefore(this.firstVisible).limitToLast(this.limit).get().then(documentSnapshots => {
      this.lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1]
      this.firstVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[0]
     }).then(() => {
      // peep the next previous query
      db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').endBefore(this.firstVisible).limitToLast(this.limit).get()
       .then(snap => {
        if (snap.size === 0) {
         //if next peeped previous button gets 0 disable
         this.prev_btn = true
         this.next_btn = false
        } else {
         //if next peeped result is does not get 0 enable buttons
         this.prev_btn = false
         this.next_btn = false
        }
       })
     })
    }
   })
  }
 },
 mounted () {
  // run first query and bind data
  this.$bind('countries', db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').limit(this.limit))
  // set last and first Visible
  db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').limit(this.limit).get().then(documentSnapshots => {
   this.lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length - 1]
   this.firstVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[0]
  }).then(() => {
            // peep to check if next should be on or off
            db.collection('Countries').orderBy('createdAt').startAfter(this.lastVisible).limit(this.limit).get()
                .then(snap => {
                    if (snap.size === 0) {
                        this.next_btn = true
                    }
                })
        })
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Any chance you can update this for Vue 3 and the new version of VueFire? I'm trying to implement it but falling short. Having lots of confusion and need some direction.